# Calling a cell value and replacing it

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

The photo attached is the spreadsheet I am working with. I have a userform that takes a spinbutton value which I defined as "cases". I can get the code to take the spinbutton value and subtract it from the cell I want, however it subtracts it from 0 and not the original value that was already in the cell. For example, I want to subtract 5 from cell C9 but instead of getting 300-5 = 295 for that cell, I am getting a value of -5.

This is my code so far:

```vb
    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 6
            'If inventorysheet.Cells(inventoryrow, 1).Value = ComboBox1 And inventorysheet.Cells(inventoryrow, 2).Value = ComboBox2 And inventorysheet.Cells(inventoryrow, 3).Value = s Then
                currentinventory = Sheets("Inventory").Range("C" & (7 * k - 2)).Cells(i, j).Value
                Exit Do
            'End If
        Next
    Next
    
    'inventoryrow = inventoryrow + 1
Loop

Sheets("Inventory").Range("C" & (7 * k - 2)).Cells(i, j) = Sheets("Inventory").Range("C" & (7 * k - 2)).Cells(i, j) - cases
```

For clarification purposes, `k` optionbutton values, `i` and `j` are combobox indexes, I do not believe these are causing me any problems.
TIA!

I cannot figure out how to get the code to pull the original value from the cell, it always just subtracts from 0.

Comment: After your two `For`s complete, the `i` and `j` become 6 and 7 respectively. Then `.Range("C" & (7 * k - 2)).Cells(i, j)` points to the cell outside of the table which is empty. In case of C5, that would be I10.

Answer (score 0):

just following up. I realized I was overcomplicating things and ended up working it out.
This is what ended up working. It turns out what I was doing before was not even the right thing to do. Thank you to GSerg for the comment as well, it allowed me to realize my mistake.

```vb
'Check the current inventory level
With Sheets("Inventory")  
    currentinventory = Sheets("Inventory").Range("C" & (7 * k - 2)).Cells(i, j).Value  
    newinventory = currentinventory - cases  
'Update the inventory level
    inventorysheet.Range("C" & (7 * k - 2)).Cells(i, j).Value = newinventory  
End With
```